# How to hide content script tab in chrome web inspector

Tags: google-chrome, web-inspector

The content script tab is useless, isn't it? How to hide it and show sources tab by default?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible unless you want to re-compile Chrome's proprietary code (if you can get it). You can do it with Chromium which is O/S.

That said, I find the content scripts tab useful when I SysAdmin Chromium browsers that have I have written custom content scripts for.